# R checkParams() function

Tags: r

Does anyone know if there is an R function called `checkParams()` and if so, could explain what it does?  I found a `checkParams` function [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SpaDES/versions/1.3.1/topics/checkParams), but I do not think this is the one being used by the code I am reading.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: This is the function I am referring to in the code below.  Please let me know if you need more code.

  
  # Read in the file, and check against expected
  
  ############
  # Check that imported params file matches format in PARAMS_TEMPLATE
  pass<- checkParams("glycoPipe", PARAMSfullFile)
  if (!pass) return()
  
  # If we got to here, we can now extract and populate the parameters
  # read in and set all the variables from the params file locally
  # Extract and populate the parameters
  paramsL<- extractParams(PARAMSfullFile)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: I am looking for the file definition in the code, something like checkParams <- function (arguments), but there is none.  The function is supposed to check that the input file matches the parameters in PARAMS_TEMPLATE file